# C++ get Processor ID

Tags: c++, windows, processor

This thread is ok. 
[How to get Processor and Motherboard Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436221/how-to-get-processor-and-motherboard-id)

I wanted to get processor ID using C++ code not using WMI or any third party lib.

OR anything on a computer that turns out to be unique. 
One thing is Ethernet ID but which is again removable on some machines. This I want to use mostly for licensing purpose.

Is processor ID unique and available on all major processors?

Comment: Must read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488249/how-do-i-enforce-an-expiration-date-for-a-trial-install-of-my-software/5488752#5488752 (especially the last two paragraphs).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had a similar problem lately and I did the following. First I gained some unique system identification values:

- **[GetVolumeInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** for HDD serial number
- **[GetComputerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** (this of course is not unique, but our system was using the computer names to identify clients on a LAN, so it was good for me)
- **[__cpuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** (and specifically the PSN - processor serial number field)
- **[GetAdaptersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** for MAC addresses

I took these values and combined them in an arbitrary but deterministic way <sup>**(read update below!)**</sup> (adding, xoring, dividing and keeping the remainder etc.). Iterate over the values as if they were strings and be creative. In the end, you will get a byte literal which you can transform to the ASCII range of letters and numbers to get a unique, "readable" code that doesn't look like noise.

Another approach can be simply concatenating these values and then "cover them up" with xoring something over them (and maybe transforming to letters again).

I'm saying it's unique, because at least one of the inputs is supposed to be unique (the MAC address). Of course you need some understanding of number theory to not blew away this uniqueness, but it should be good enough anyway.

**Important update**: Since this post I learned a few things about cryptography, and I'm on the opinion that making up an arbitrary combination (essentially your own hash) is almost certainly a bad idea. Hash functions used in practice are constructed to be well-behaved (as in low probability of collisions) and to be hard to break (the ability construct a value that has the same hash value as another). Constructing such a function is a very hard computer science problem and unless you are qualified, you shouldn't attempt. The correct approach for this is to concatenate whatever information you can collect about the hardware (i.e. the ones I listed in the post) and use a cryptographic hash or digital signature to get a verifiable and secure output. Do not implement the cryptographic algorithms yourself either; there are lots of vulnerability pitfalls that take lots of knowledge to avoid. Use a well-known and trusted library for the implementation of the algorithms.

Comment: Good @Tamás But VolumeInformation is not reliable. If you format the harddisk then It will get changed and the old generated license won't work. Another thinks is there are lot of tools available to change the volumeID as we want. Computer Name also configurable and there are tools to emulate/overwrite the MAC address. In this case customer can break the license easily.

Comment: probubly lose the mac address, then jush hash that, save the hash, and compare against it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Visual Studio, Microsoft provides the [`__cpuid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instrinsic in the `<intrin.h>` header. Example on the linked msdn site.

Comment: That is the CPU _type_. Hardly unique; there can be billions of duplicates. E.g. from the linked page, you can get "Genuine Intel(R) CPU 2.80GHz" plus some bit flags.

Answer (score 3):

Hm...

There are special libraries to generate unique ID based on the hardware installed (so for the specified computer this ID always be the same). Most of them takes motherboard ID + HDD ID + CPU ID and mix these values.

Whe reinvent the wheel? Why not to use these libraries? Any serious reason?

Comment: which are the libs, name would help me

Comment: 1. [DLL + sources](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/hardware%20ID%20programmer%27s%20DLL.html) 2. [sources + article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/computerinfo.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use command line.

```
wmic cpu list full

wmic baseboard list full
```

Or WMI interface

```
#include <wmi.hpp>
#include <wmiexception.hpp>
#include <wmiresult.hpp>

#include <../src/wmi.cpp>
#include <../src/wmiresult.cpp> // used

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

struct Win32_WmiCpu
{

    void setProperties(const WmiResult& result, std::size_t index)
    {
        //EXAMPLE EXTRACTING PROPERTY TO CLASS
        result.extract(index, "ProcessorId", (*this).m_cpuID);
    }

    static std::string getWmiClassName()
    {
        return "Win32_Processor";
    }

    string m_cpuID;
    //All the other properties you wish to read from WMI

}; //end struct Win32_ComputerSystem
   
struct Win32_WmiMotherBoard
{

    void setProperties(const WmiResult& result, std::size_t index)
    {
        //EXAMPLE EXTRACTING PROPERTY TO CLASS
        result.extract(index, "SerialNumber", (*this).m_mBId);
    }

    static std::string getWmiClassName()
    {
        return "Win32_BaseBoard";
    }

    string m_mBId;

}; //end struct Win32_ComputerSystem


try
{
    const Win32_WmiCpu cpu = Wmi::retrieveWmi<Win32_WmiCpu>();
    strncpy_s(ret.m_cpu, cpu.m_cpuID.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);
}
catch (const Wmi::WmiException& )
{
}
try
{
    const Win32_WmiMotherBoard mb = Wmi::retrieveWmi<Win32_WmiMotherBoard>();
    strncpy_s(ret.m_mb, mb.m_mBId.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);
}
catch (const Wmi::WmiException& )
{
}
```