# What's the format of Win32_Processor.ProcessorId?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to generate random ProcessorId, in order to do that, I need to figure out its format.

The ProcessorId on my computer:

> Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT NAME, ProcessorId FROM Win32_Processor"

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_Processor
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        :
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
Name             : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz
ProcessorId      : BFEBFBFF000306A9
PSComputerName   :
```

The ProcessorId property from WMI has following description:

> Processor information that describes the processor features. For an
>   x86 class CPU, the field format depends on the processor support of
>   the CPUID instruction. If the instruction is supported, the property
>   contains 2 (two) DWORD formatted values. The first is an offset of
>   08h-0Bh, which is the EAX value that a CPUID instruction returns with
>   input EAX set to 1. The second is an offset of 0Ch-0Fh, which is the
>   EDX value that the instruction returns. Only the first two bytes of
>   the property are significant and contain the contents of the DX
>   register at CPU reset—all others are set to 0 (zero), and the contents
>   are in DWORD format.
>
> This value comes from the Processor ID member of the Processor
>   Information structure in the SMBIOS information.

Can anyone explain deeply the format of **Win32_Processor.ProcessorId**?

How to generate it from function **__cpuid**?

(The method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10229673/1633272) doesn't work.)

Comment: It is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-process): "Data type: uint32".  Matches the winapi declaration, DWORD.  It is not a random number.

Answer (score 2):

I still don't understand the ProcessorId description very well.

This code generate exactly the same string with Win32_Processor.ProcessorId.

```
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string GetProcessorId() {
    std::array<int, 4> cpuInfo;
    __cpuid(cpuInfo.data(), 1);
    std::ostringstream buffer;
    buffer
        << std::uppercase << std::hex << std::setfill('0')
        << std::setw(8) << cpuInfo.at(3)
        << std::setw(8) << cpuInfo.at(0);
    return buffer.str();
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << GetProcessorId() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```